# Creating date table from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I have been trying to figure out how to create a table out of this code, but can not figure it out. Thank You so much for any answers.

```
WITH 
  dat_param AS (SELECT SYSDATE AS dat FROM dual)

SELECT 
  LEVEL AS day_year
  ,TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1 AS date_year
  ,TO_CHAR(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1,'YYYY-MM') AS part_year
  ,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1,'D')) AS day_week

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YEAR'),12)-TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YEAR')
```

Comment: each "select dat from dat_param" can be replaced by sysdate tout court.  No need for the CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle, you can use `CREATE TABLE AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE t as
    WITH 
      dat_param AS (SELECT SYSDATE AS dat FROM dual)    
    SELECT 
      LEVEL AS day_year
      ,TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1 AS date_year
      ,TO_CHAR(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1,'YYYY-MM') AS part_year
      ,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YYYY')+LEVEL-1,'D')) AS day_week    
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YEAR'),12)-TRUNC((SELECT dat FROM dat_param),'YEAR');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eaab283ae8cc677ef61dc46fe8613bd4) is a db<>fiddle.